# OCR multipage PDF as multipage TIFF with PHP Imagick/Tesseract

Tags: php, tesseract, tiff, imagick

I am using PHP/Imagick to convert a multipage PDF to a TIFF, so it can be scanned with Tesseract OCR. It converts correctly into a multi-page TIFF. (Although, just 6 pages long but 1.2GB!)

My code is:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->setResolution(600,600);
$imagick->readImage(storage_path('app/ocr/'.$fileid.".pdf"));
$imagick->setImageFormat('tiff');
$imagick->setImageDepth(8); //Required for Tesseract
$imagick->writeImage(storage_path('app/ocrtemp/'.$fileid.'.tiff'));

$tesseract = new Tesseract();
$text = $tesseract->recognize(storage_path('app/ocrtemp/'.$fileid.'.tiff'));
```

The OCR works nicely, and returns the OCR text of the last page of the TIFF. BUT, only the last page. How can I get Tesseract to scan a multipage TIFF for me?

Any ideas of what I can do?

I understand Imagick should do this correctly, but I think it also has a feature where it can stick images together - maybe I should do this and just create one really long JPG or something and OCR that?

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: If at all possible avoid using Tiff. It is one of the worst "standards" ever. I'd strongly recommend just writing each of the pages out to a separate file using `$imagick->writeImages("./filepath.jpg", false)`  and then get Tesseract to read them individually.

Comment: @Danack OK, I've not had any luck so I'll think I'll try this way.

Comment: Actually - I meant PNG not jpg. It might be marginally slower than JPG, but also possibly slightly faster, but using JPG as an intermediate format anywhere is usually a bad idea.